# MySQL Trigger to start Java Application

Tags: java, mysql, sql, triggers

I have a web application that inserts a row with a future time in the MySQL DB. When the current time is equal to the set time in the entry, I want a java application to start doing some work based on the values in the entry.

1. How can I create a timer per row in the table that can trigger the event when the time matches?
2. How do I spawn a new java application when a timer expiry. Yes I need a single application for every row that shoot off this trigger.

Any pointers to the framework or sample code is appreciated. I am thinking polling the table could be tedious for a large dataset.

Comment: Do you mean application or class? You might be able to create a custom java event, but I don't know much about MySQL

Comment: This is just the world upside down. Architecturally I would expect a Java application to do work when it figures out that it is time to do so, not database booting up their own clients. Poll rather than push.

Answer (score 1):

mysql trigger can not call java application but I think Oracle can do that. do googling..

Answer (score 1):

Create just one java application which checks the table every second and gets rows to be executed. If such a row is found run appropriate code.

You can use `Timer` or take a look at http://quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.x/examples/

Answer (score 0):

i think you need to see  [Event Generators - Oracle Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13214_01/wli/docs85/manage/evntgen.html)